Android app to hook in running other educational apps in the middle of game apps managed by parent users via Family Link-(like) app
I am looking for an API that will allow parents to interface with the availability of apps on children's phones, actually, the Family Link so already does this.
But, what would be useful, to parents', and children's, learning, alike...
Would be an app to hook into the games on the parents' phone to make sure that once progress is made in the game the app fires up another app where a certain level needs to be completed in order for the child to successfully return back to the game.
For this, an API is needed that allows:

the parent to hook into apps to game stages

the game reports to the advanced family link (like) app, what the stages are (and the parents hook into the educational apps at the various stages)


This, is basically, a three-placeholder-app listener-observer design pattern.
There are three instances of the listener-observer design pattern because the three, family link, placeholder game, placeholder educational app, apps, if each app is a node in the K3 Kuratowski graph then the edges are three.
So, this way, parents would be able to hook into educational games at various game progress stages in game apps.
Children, might engage more, with game apps (but this way wouldn't be missing out, on, other, heavier, more important, educational progress).
In order for this to work, an API needs to be provided (perhaps, with the support, of the Android system), to have these places in the code where via perhaps a dynamic configuration file for each app configurable via the family link like app, the educational apps can be inserted, given various criteria, to be fired up.
The criteria that make more sense seen to be, "level completed".
Thanks.
